# ggplot dodge not grouping bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why isnt the dodge parameter creating multiple bars for each group? I was going for a grouped bar plot, not the stacked one I got.

```
df<-data.frame(c(40,23,18,41,15,14,38,21,1),c(rep("Do you agree with \nthe 'Hands Up' protestors ?",3),rep("Have the Police alienated themselves\n from the Public?",3),rep("Are the public ignoring the\n dangers Police face everyday?",3)),c("49%","28%","22%","59%","21%","20%","63%","35%","2%"),c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
colnames(df)<-c("values","names","percentages","group")



ggplot(df,aes(names,values,group=group))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge",fill=rep(c("green","red","orange"),3))+
  geom_text(aes(label=percentages))+
  ylab("number of votes")+
  xlab("")+
  ggtitle("Police Opinion polls")
```

My results:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need a column in your dataframe that actually distinguishes what the different values are (I've made a guess). Then map that column to the fill aesthetic within an `aes()` call for `ggplot` to properly dodge the values:

```
df$response = rep(c("Yes", "No", "Unsure"), 3)

dodger = position_dodge(width = 0.9)
ggplot(df,aes(names,values, fill = response))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = dodger)+
    geom_text(aes(label=percentages), position = dodger)+
    ylab("number of votes")+
    xlab("")+
    ggtitle("Police Opinion polls")
```

The `dodger = position_dodge(width = 0.9)` line is needed because `geom_text` has to be dodged manually with a specified width.

Comment: I tested your code, bit didnt get the grouped bar plot I was looking for. I updated my code with an example, I apologize if my request was unclear

Comment: I used the example data you posted, added the code in my answer and got a dodged bar plot. Can you explain what result you *do* get from running my code with the example data so I can identify where it's going wrong?

Comment: My bad- I didn't notice we were using two different columns for the df$response. I based it off the `group` variable while you used `response`